# SQL Server Repeat first row for each node and get same row number for hierarchy node

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I have multiple nested cte that return this result

```
WITH X AS (    
  SELECT BATCH, CHILD_BATCH, 0 AS LVL, 
  N'/' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),BATCH) + N'/' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),CHILD_BATCH) + N'/' AS HIERARCHY
  FROM MYTABLE
  WHERE BATCH = @LOTTO_INIZIALE  

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T.BATCH, T.CHILD_BATCH, X.LVL + 1 AS LVL, X.HIERARCHY + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), L.CHILD_BATCH) + N'/'
  FROM MYTABLE T INNER JOIN X ON T.BATCH = X.CHILD_BATCH  
)
SELECT * FROM X

╔════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════╦═════╗
║ BATCH  ║ CHILD_BATCH ║                  HIERARCHY                  ║ LVL ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════╣
║ NZ1677 ║ NZ1671      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/                             ║   0 ║
║ NZ1671 ║ NZ1646      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/NZ1646/                      ║   1 ║
║ NZ1646 ║ NZ1125      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/NZ1646/NZ1125/               ║   2 ║
║ NZ1125 ║ NZ0960      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/NZ1646/NZ1125/NZ0960/        ║   3 ║
║ NZ0960 ║ NY2443      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/NZ1646/NZ1125/NZ0960/NY2443/ ║   4 ║
║ NZ1677 ║ NZ1672      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/                             ║   0 ║
║ NZ1672 ║ NZ1646      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1646/                      ║   1 ║
║ NZ1646 ║ NZ1125      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1646/NZ1125/               ║   2 ║
║ NZ1125 ║ NZ0960      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1646/NZ1125/NZ0960/        ║   3 ║
║ NZ0960 ║ NY2443      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1646/NZ1125/NZ0960/NY2443/ ║   4 ║
║ NZ1672 ║ NZ1647      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1647/                      ║   1 ║
║ NZ1647 ║ NZ1444      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1647/NZ1444/               ║   2 ║
║ NZ1444 ║ NZ1442      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1647/NZ1444/NZ1442/        ║   3 ║
║ NZ1442 ║ NY2443      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1647/NZ1444/NZ1442/NY2443/ ║   4 ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════╩═════╝
```

I wish to get a new column with the same value for the same hierarchy node, like this :

```sql
╔════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════╦═════╦═════╗
║ BATCH  ║ CHILD_BATCH ║                  HIERARCHY                  ║ LVL ║ IX  ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════╬═════╣
║ NZ1677 ║ NZ1671      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/                             ║   0 ║   1 ║
║ NZ1671 ║ NZ1646      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/NZ1646/                      ║   1 ║   1 ║
║ NZ1646 ║ NZ1125      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/NZ1646/NZ1125/               ║   2 ║   1 ║
║ NZ1125 ║ NZ0960      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/NZ1646/NZ1125/NZ0960/        ║   3 ║   1 ║
║ NZ0960 ║ NY2443      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1671/NZ1646/NZ1125/NZ0960/NY2443/ ║   4 ║   1 ║
║ NZ1677 ║ NZ1672      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/                             ║   0 ║   2 ║
║ NZ1672 ║ NZ1646      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1646/                      ║   1 ║   2 ║
║ NZ1646 ║ NZ1125      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1646/NZ1125/               ║   2 ║   2 ║
║ NZ1125 ║ NZ0960      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1646/NZ1125/NZ0960/        ║   3 ║   2 ║
║ NZ0960 ║ NY2443      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1646/NZ1125/NZ0960/NY2443/ ║   4 ║   2 ║
║ NZ1672 ║ NZ1647      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1647/                      ║   1 ║   3 ║
║ NZ1647 ║ NZ1444      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1647/NZ1444/               ║   2 ║   3 ║
║ NZ1444 ║ NZ1442      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1647/NZ1444/NZ1442/        ║   3 ║   3 ║
║ NZ1442 ║ NY2443      ║ /NZ1677/NZ1672/NZ1647/NZ1444/NZ1442/NY2443/ ║   4 ║   3 ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════╩═════╩═════╝
```

Is it possible ?

I wish also to repeat the level 0 if there are sereveral hierarchyd child nodes. (eg. /NZ1677/NZ1672/)

**EDIT**

It's a little complicated to explain but i try.

In my table I have a list of batch with one or more child.

For every hierarchy level I can have one o plus child levels.

In every row I have the quantity of batch and child.

e.g another batch can be like this (I added also the "prev_batch" column if can be help) :

```
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+-----+
| PREV_BATCH | BATCH  | CHILD_BATCH | BATCH_QTY | CHILD_QTY |       HIERARCHY        | LVL |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+-----+
|            | NB0166 | NA1367M     |  119.3700 |    0.0450 | /NB0166/NA1367M/       |   0 |
|            | NB0166 | NA1938M     |  119.3700 |    0.0650 | /NB0166/NA1938M/       |   0 |
|            | NB0166 | NA3204S     |  119.3700 |    0.0270 | /NB0166/NA3204S/       |   0 |
|            | NB0166 | NB0019      |  119.3700 |   18.0400 | /NB0166/NB0019/        |   0 |
| NB0166     | NB0019 | NA3938      |  109.6700 |  100.0000 | /NB0166/NB0019/NA3938/ |   1 |
|            | NB0166 | NB0021      |  119.3700 |   91.9600 | /NB0166/NB0021/        |   0 |
| NB0166     | NB0021 | NA1924      |  109.7400 |   40.0000 | /NB0166/NB0021/NA1924/ |   1 |
| NB0166     | NB0021 | NA2251      |  109.7400 |   10.0000 | /NB0166/NB0021/NA2251/ |   1 |
| NB0166     | NB0021 | NA2616      |  109.7400 |   50.0000 | /NB0166/NB0021/NA2616/ |   1 |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+-----+
```

My idea is add the IX column (like I explain upper) with the same value for every hierarchy node.

I want to use the lead function to read the quantity of the next level batch (I need to do some calcule).

With the IX column I can partition the lead correctly.

Opened to some best idea to accomplish this task.

Comment: Aside: What does `;WITH` terminate? Why isn't the statement [terminated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: post edited to clarify

Comment: I would assume that BATCH_QTY = SUM(CHILD_QTY) but that is not what your data suggests. Can you clarify how the quantity columns in your data relate to eachother?

Comment: Batch quantity is not the sum of children because it is the quantity produced by a product from its own raw material. The reasoning is also reflected for each child batch.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an increase when the previous row is at a deeper level than the current row.

This is probably simplest using `LAG()` and a cumulative sum:

```
WITH X AS (    
  SELECT BATCH, CHILD_BATCH, 0 AS LVL, 
         (N'/' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),BATCH) + N'/' + 
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),CHILD_BATCH) + N'/'
         ) AS HIERARCHY
  FROM MYTABLE
  WHERE BATCH = @LOTTO_INIZIALE  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT T.BATCH, T.CHILD_BATCH, X.LVL + 1 AS LVL,
         (X.HIERARCHY + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), L.CHILD_BATCH) + N'/')
  FROM MYTABLE T INNER JOIN
       X
       ON T.BATCH = X.CHILD_BATCH  
)
SELECT X.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_lvl < lvl THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY HIERARCHY) as IX
FROM (SELECT X.*,
             LAG(LVL) OVER (ORDER BY HIERARCHY) as prev_lvl
      FROM X
     ) X;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not matter in your situation but I would recommend that the record have a "parent" column rather than a "child" column. This is because in many circumstances when you are inserting a record with a parent/child relationship the "parent" already exists whereas the child may not be inserted until a later date. This means that when you are inserting the record you have all the information you need at hand rather than having to go and update the row once the child is inserted. Also a child will usually only have one parent but a parent record can have any number of children. You can also enforce referential integrity more easily.

Anyway onto your problem.

I have interpreted the following as you requiring a "0" record for every "group". That is why there is an additional "0" record in my output that is not in yours.

> I wish also to repeat the level 0 if there are several hierarchy child nodes.

Given that IX is just a way to create groups on the "grandchild", I wondered if there might be a requirement to group on any of the available descendant levels, so I have parameterized that. I don't have enough variance in the data to test this but it looks like it should work.

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE
(   BATCH CHAR(6),
    CHILD_BATCH CHAR(6)
)

DECLARE @LOTTO_INIZIALE CHAR(6) = 'NZ1677'
DECLARE @GROUPING_LEVEL INT     = 1 -- 1 = grandchild, 2 = great-grandchild... n = nth descendant +2 (given our base is child)

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE
VALUES ('NZ1677', 'NZ1671'),
       ('NZ1671', 'NZ1646'),
       ('NZ1646', 'NZ1125'),
       ('NZ1125', 'NZ0960'),
       ('NZ0960', 'NY2443'),
       ('NZ1677', 'NZ1672'),
       ('NZ1672', 'NZ1646'),
       ('NZ1646', 'NZ1125'),
       ('NZ1125', 'NZ0960'),
       ('NZ0960', 'NY2443'),
       ('NZ1672', 'NZ1647'),
       ('NZ1647', 'NZ1444'),
       ('NZ1444', 'NZ1442'),
       ('NZ1442', 'NY2443')

;WITH cte_batch_hierarchy
   AS (SELECT BATCH, 
              CHILD_BATCH,
              GRP              = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '/') + BATCH + '/' + CHILD_BATCH + '/',
              HIERARCHY        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '/') + BATCH + '/' + CHILD_BATCH + '/',
              LVL              = 0
         FROM @MYTABLE  t
        WHERE t.BATCH = @LOTTO_INIZIALE 
        UNION ALL
       SELECT mt.BATCH, 
              mt.CHILD_BATCH,
              GRP = CASE WHEN bh.LVL < @GROUPING_LEVEL THEN HIERARCHY + mt.CHILD_BATCH  + '/' ELSE GRP END,
              HIERARCHY = HIERARCHY + mt.CHILD_BATCH  + '/',
              LVL       = LVL + 1
         FROM cte_batch_hierarchy bh
         JOIN @MYTABLE mt ON bh.CHILD_BATCH = mt.BATCH
      )
SELECT bh.BATCH, 
       bh.CHILD_BATCH, 
       bh.HIERARCHY, 
       bh.LVL, 
       IX = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ISNULL(grp.GRP, bh.GRP)) 
  FROM cte_batch_hierarchy bh
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT GRP 
               FROM cte_batch_hierarchy 
              WHERE LVL > @GROUPING_LEVEL) grp ON grp.GRP LIKE bh.HIERARCHY + '%'
 GROUP BY
       bh.BATCH, 
       bh.CHILD_BATCH, 
       bh.HIERARCHY, 
       bh.LVL,
       ISNULL(grp.GRP, bh.GRP)
 ORDER BY 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ISNULL(grp.GRP, bh.GRP)),
       LVL
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for the example given, but how can I do it if I do not know from the outset the number of children that each node can have ?

Comment: to complete the information, i need use the IX field to be able to use the lead function partitioning only for descending layers

Comment: I don't understand what more you are looking for from either of those comments. Can you update the question with the additional requirements. There is more space there to be clear.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I've edited the post, I hope it's clearer now.